# Still cannot install Halo: Combat Evolved

Tags: 12.04, wine

I have been trying all week to install Halo: Combat Evolved on my laptop. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and Wine 1.6.2. I insert the game disc into the disc drive and it loads. I start setup and enter my product key, but then it says cannot load pidgen.dll. I looked on the forums and added pidgen.dll and mfc42.dll to .wine/drive_c/windows/system32 folders. It still says that it cannot load pidgen.dll. I also tried PlayOnLinux but Halo is not listed in the program list. What else can I possibly do to get Halo to install, or is it just a lost cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed CrossOver 12.5.0 and purchased the license for full unlimited use. Then I created a winxp bottle and installed .NET 3.5 framework and Visual C++ 6.0 redistributable before installing Halo. In the end I had to spend money to play my copy of Halo.